# android.view.InflateException: on Intent

Tags: android, memory, layout

I have a problem with an intent I get an InflatException. This happens when I click on any of the Buttons of a Main activity that is a Menu. acording to the log Cat I know that the problem should be on the xml of the main Activity.

I tried to compress more the images of the main Activity but nothing, so I thought using finish(); after calling intents would free memory to help me solve this issue but nothing, any ideas will be greatly appreciated

Update: the memory error appears after the intent not when inlfating this layout, the activity I'm trying to launch is empty right now, it only has the same background, i didn't program it yet... so that was i think is a rare error

update2: all the xml files of selectors

the XML file of the Main Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/basegenerica"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/twtbtm"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/facebtm"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/tww"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/facebtm"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/face"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/facebtm"
            android:id="@+id/logobancovw"
            android:background="@drawable/logobanco" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/beneficiosbtm"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logobancovw"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@layout/btnbeneficios"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/consultabtm"
            android:layout_below="@+id/beneficiosbtm"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@layout/btnconsulta"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cajerobtm"
            android:layout_below="@+id/consultabtm"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@layout/btncajeros"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/promobtm"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cajerobtm"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@layout/btnpromo"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/indicadoresbtm"
            android:layout_below="@+id/promobtm"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@layout/btnindicadores"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/faqbtm"
            android:layout_below="@+id/indicadoresbtm"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@layout/btnfaq"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contactobtm"
            android:layout_below="@+id/faqbtm"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@layout/btncontacto"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/soportebtm"
            android:layout_below="@+id/contactobtm"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@layout/btnemergencias"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The logCat of the Error:

```
05-16 15:53:03.864: D/dalvikvm(804): GC freed 134 objects / 5968 bytes in 51ms
05-16 15:53:04.094: D/dalvikvm(804): GC freed 104 objects / 5248 bytes in 51ms
05-16 15:53:13.714: D/dalvikvm(804): GC freed 315 objects / 19056 bytes in 54ms
05-16 15:53:14.064: E/dalvikvm-heap(804): 4830936-byte external allocation too large for this process.
05-16 15:53:14.064: E/(804): VM won't let us allocate 4830936 bytes
05-16 15:53:14.064: D/AndroidRuntime(804): Shutting down VM
05-16 15:53:14.064: W/dalvikvm(804): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-16 15:53:14.074: E/AndroidRuntime(804): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ketanolab.banca.movil/com.ketanolab.banca.movil.soporte}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at com.ketanolab.banca.movil.soporte.onCreate(soporte.java:29)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  ... 11 more
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:92)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  ... 21 more
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1705)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1850)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1799)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:284)
05-16 15:53:14.094: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  ... 25 more
05-16 15:53:14.124: I/dalvikvm(804): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
```

the btncontacto xml layout file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/contacto" />    
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/contactoapre" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/contacto" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/contacto" />
</selector>
```

the btnbeneficios XML

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/beneficios" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/beneficiossombra" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/beneficios" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/beneficios" />
</selector>
```

the btncajeros XML

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/loccajeros" />    
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/loccajerosapre" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/loccajeros" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/loccajeros" />
</selector>
```

the btnconsulta XML

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/consulta" />    
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/consultaapre" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/consulta" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/consulta" />
</selector>
```

the btnemergencias XML

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/emergencia" />    
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/emergenciaapre" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/emergencia" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:dr
```

awable="@drawable/emergencia" />

the brnfaq XML

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tips" />    
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/tipssombra" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/tips" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/tips" />
</selector>
```

the btnindicadores XML

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/indicadores" />    
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/indicadoresapre" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/indicadores" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/indicadores" />
</selector>
```

the btnpromo XML

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/promociones" />    
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/promocionesapre" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/promociones" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/promociones" />
</selector>
```

Comment: How big are your drawables? In your layout XML you've got a lot of them. The crash indicates that it is trying to allocate 5MB

Comment: 5k for each button 15 k for the first button and 40k for the background

Comment: never noticed that one is allowed to insert LAYOUTS as Background resource... I Always thought that it can be Color or Drawable ONLY

Comment: updated answer with more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:background="@layout/btnconsulta"`!!

I assume you want to say

```
android:background="@drawable/btnconsulta"
```

as i know you can't inflate a layout for background!!

use colors or drawable for your background or selector if you want your buttons get different style on multiple state

pressed,
 focused
...

Comment: thats what I mentioned in my comment

Comment: I used this type of backgrounds on other apps to make a onclick effect different from the usual that comes with android, I'LL update my answer with the layout xml

Comment: your selector put it in res/drawable not res/layout

Comment: that's what is causing your problem fail to inflate layout!! selector aren't layout they are StateListDrawable

Comment: I migrated all the selectors to drawable but I still have the same error

Comment: i don't no why you get Out of memory besides your images don't look too big for me. im gonna try it on my pc

Comment: you are using 5kb for your image size!!

Comment: hope also that you are not calling another selector from one of your selector. Sure that will cause an out of memory!!

Comment: yes is something strange, I'm using another app menu as a base and I didn't have the problem

Comment: Updated all the selectos xml files pasted

Comment: @K_Anas I've solved it already, I tried to compile on my frieds computer and everything was working perfect, so I reinstalled eclipse and there's no error anymore.... I really appreciate you help me a lot!!